# Nginx doesn't show the default html page

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi

I'm running nginx on raspberry pi.

I ran update and upgrade commands and then installed nginx.

```
1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get upgrade
3. sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Started the server

```
4. sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

Output

```
[ ok ] Starting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.service.
```

When I enter ip address into the browser nothing appears. What could be the problem here?

Comment: is it just a blank page or do you get an error? Is this a clen RPI install?

Comment: @TonyHensler It's just blank (white). No error. Clean install.

Comment: What is in your /var/www/html folder?

Comment: @TonyHensler There wasn't www/html/ it was nginx/html/index.html. I renamed html to www and edited the root in default file to root /var/www;

Comment: @TonyHensler I restarted the server, and now I can see 403 forbidden.

Comment: Should you not have pointed it to root nginx/www? can you prodive the code in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: @TonyHensler Never mind. I fixed it. I changed the root to "root /usr/share/nginx/www;" Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad I could help push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

Changed the root in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

from `root /var/www/html;`

to `root /usr/share/nginx/www;`

I also renamed `html` folder to `www` because it was missing.

Restarted nginx for the changes to take effect.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```